# Python: Handling Multiple Independent Exceptions

Tags: python, exception

I have a class method that takes two arguments. If both fail a test, I want to convey that and halt execution.

Two try blocks each with a print statement in their except block conveys the information I want. But it does not halt execution. E.g. the following code prints "out" even if one or both of the variables cannot be cast as an int.

```
try:
    A = int(A)
except ValueError: 
    print("Argument %a must be an integer." %A)
try: 
    B = int(B)
except ValueError:
    print("Argument %a must be an integer." %B)
print("out")
```

I can halt execution by using raise in the except block, but then argument B is not tested for int if argument A raises ValueError. E.g. if A cannot be cast as an int in the following code, it raises ValueError for A but then halts without testing B:

```
try:
    A = int(A)
except ValueError: 
    raise ValueError("Argument %a must be an integer." %A)
try: 
    B = int(B)
except ValueError:
    raise ValueError("Argument %a must be an integer." %B)
print("out")
```

In the cases where both A and B cannot be cast as ints, how do I convey that information and halt execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could flag the first error and reraise if the second error is hit. One option is a list that accumulates error messages for the reraise.

```
def foo(A, B):
    errors = []
    try:
        A = int(A)
    except ValueError: 
        errors.append("Argument %a must be an integer." %A)
        print(errors[-1])
    try: 
        B = int(B)
    except ValueError:
        errors.append("Argument %a must be an integer." %B)
        print(errors[-1])
        if len(errors) > 1:
            raise ValueError(", ".join(errors))
    print("out")
```

If you want to try both conversions but error if either fails, just change that final check.

```
def foo(A, B):
    errors = []
    try:
        A = int(A)
    except ValueError: 
        errors.append("Argument %a must be an integer." %A)
        print(errors[-1])
    try: 
        B = int(B)
    except ValueError:
        errors.append("Argument %a must be an integer." %B)
        print(errors[-1])
    if errors:
        raise ValueError(", ".join(errors))
    print("out")
```

Comment: Neat, thanks. Your code still prints "out" if only one of the arguments is not an int.

Comment: Right, but I think that's what you asked for. If you want to fail in either case a quick change will fix it.